# Fast Fourier Transform on Meshes

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalues, mesh, fourier-transform, laplacian

I have a (closed, manifold, oriented) triangular mesh for which I build a matrix $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ discretising the negated Laplace-Beltrami operator. The matrix $L$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. For small $n$ I can compute the eigendecomposition $L=VDV^*$. Then the counterpart of a Fourier transform would be given by $F[x] = V^* x$. Are there known (efficient iterative) methods to approximately compute the matrix-vector multiplication $V^*x$ without forming $V^*$ explicitly, i.e. just using (some iterative method on) the sparse matrix $L$? Also methods for computing approximately $Dz$?

Edit: As a clarification - I am thinking of something like Lanczos, and since at each iteration $k$ I have $LQ_k = Q_kT_k + \beta_{k+1}v_{k+1}e^T_k$, and $\tilde{L}_k = Q_k T_k Q_k^T$, the eigenvectors of $\tilde{L}_k$ are the eigenvectors $U_k$ of $T_k$ times $Q_k$: $V_k = Q_kU_k$, and I am actually only interested in the product $V_k^T x=(Q_kU_k)^Tx$. It is clear that for $k=n$ I get the exact result. The issue is that I would really like to avoid storing the $Q_k$, $T_k$, $U_k$ etc. and instead I hoped there was an iterative method that updates things without such storage requirements, i.e. not unlike how Lanczos-based iterative methods are formulated. I am not very familiar with the references on the subject however.

Comment: Do you need the projection of $x$ onto every basis vector in $V$ or just, say, a  subset that well-approximates $x$?

Comment: @whpowell96 Ideally I would like an iterative method that can exploit the sparsity of  $L$ in order to compute an approximation of $V^*x$, the approximation quality can then depend on a stopping criterion. Although a subset is also interesting - I assume I can get the latter through some modification of Lanczos?

Comment: My thoughts are that computing a projection onto all eigenvectors would probably require $n$ evaluations of some matvec, whereas it may be possible to get a good approximation in some subset of an eigenbasis by starting with a Krylov basis or something similar that can be computed with hopefully far fewer than $n$ matvec. Will have to think more on the details.

Comment: @whpowell96 Sure, the FFT exploits the structure of the eigenvectors in the regular grid case, which makes things much more efficient. There is no guarantee that the eigenvectors in the above have such a "hierarchical" structure, where one could apply divide and conquer. I am not yet at the point of how to speed it up. One could of course compute the eigendecomposition and then perform the matrix-vector mult, but my hope was that I don't need to explicitly form $V$ to compute $V^*x$, similarly to how I don't need to form $A^{-1}$ to compute $A^{-1}x$.

Comment: [LOBPCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOBPCG) could be a good alternative to Lanczos. It might give you more freedom to make different tradeoffs about how many eigenvector / eigenvalue pairs you have to store.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the matrix $V$ will be dense, even if $L$ is sparse.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth It was probably unclear from my original question - but this is why I mentioned that I can compute $L=VDV^T$ for small $n$. When $n$ gets larger I cannot even store this, let alone compute it. This is why I wanted an iterative method that iteratively updates my vector and converges to the matrix-vector product $V^Tx$. My hope was that at least for symmetric matrices one can use some kind of e.g. three term recursion to avoid storing and using all vectors in $V$, similar to what Lanczos-based iterative solvers do for solving linear systems.